# Using the predefined colors in .NET

Tags: colors

Surely this has been asked before but I am not finding the answer so...

I am changing the backColor in a tool strip with code. When I go into the GUI editor for the back color I am presented with pre-named colors. The color I am interested in is "System->Control"

[image]

When I try to specify this color in C# code the color "Control" does not exist:

[image]

How do I use the predefined colors presented in the GUI editor in my code?

Comment: What happens when you select Control, save the file.  Can you look at the .cs file in Notepad++ and see what it defaults it to?

Comment: Ah! Good idea it is             `this.statusStrip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the clue from @MiscellaneousUser in the comments above the proper form appears to be:

```
public Color StatusStripColor => SystemColors.Control;
```